# Double obstructing wall problem, what is the optimal walk path and length?

Tags: integration, derivatives, graph-theory, optimization, simulation

Every day, you walk from point A to point B which are exactly $2$ miles apart straight line distance, however, each day, there is a $50$% chance of there being an obstructing wall perpendicular to the direct AB segment.  The wall cannot be seen so you wont know it is there until you actually bump it.  It is like an invisible force field that forces you to walk around it when you bump it and you will know immediately when you have cleared it , thus you can change your path once cleared.  The wall extends $1$ mile in both directions perpendicular to the direct AB path so if that wall is at the midpoint of AB, it would create a symmetrical + shape with the direct AB path.  Additionally, there is a 2nd obstructing wall that we have to deal with $25$% of the time (on average) but is only half of the length of the larger wall so it extends only $.5$ miles in both directions perpendicular to the direct AB path.  The $2$ walls can be present independently of each other.

You can assume all ground is flat and that neither wall will ever be within the first or last half mile of the direct path line segment between A and B.  That is, the $2$ walls can only be in the middle mile between A and B if at all.  For any given walk, there could be $0$, $1$, or $2$ walls present.    Also, any walls will be uniformly distributed in the middle mile.  If the $2$ walls are at the same exact spot, you can just treat that as if only the large wall is present since the obstruction would be identical.

What walk strategy will minimize the walk distance on average going from A to B?  That is, if you were to connect the dots of all the optimal (x,y) coordinates to be at during an average walk, what would the shape of the path look like (on a non-wall day)?

What is that minimum average distance to walk?

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you encounter a wall? Do you walk up to the end of the wall and then back to the original path, along the other side of the wall, or can you head off directly to B?

Comment: Why didn't you mention the question on Puzzling SE that motivated this one? (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30947/11806)

Comment: When you bump a wall, you must walk along it but after you clear the end of it, you are free to then walk in any direction, including directly at B but ask yourself would that be an optimal thing to do? What if you hit the small wall first and early on (say at mile marker $0.6$), there is still a good chance that the large wall will appear before mile marker $1.5$ so maybe walking directly at B after a wall encounter is not optimal, especially if you bump the small wall first. I didn't mention the puzzle that motivated this cuz this one has increased in complexity so much so is much different.

Comment: I will start with the simplest case, which is to always try to walk directly from A to B unless a wall is present then just go around it and once clear from the wall, immediately go back to the AB centerline, thus anticipating no more walls. Clearly this is not optimal but I want to get a baseline walk length so that we can explore many other walk paths to see which is best. For example, once hitting a wall, perhaps then walking along a diagonal (slope 1 or -1) to get back to the direct AB line. It will also be interesting to see what up slope is optimal from A since no wall first $1/2$ mile.

Comment: Why didn't you mention [this previous math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745083)?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. You need to specify the joint distribution of the two walls. Perhaps you intended to imply that they appear independently of each other?

Comment: The $2$ walls can be considered to randomly "show up" independently of each other.  I am not sure if it makes things more or less complicated if we say the $2$ walls can never be in the same spot or they can be.  Someone can tell me which is simpler to compute and I will update the question to specify that.  This is similar to my previous obstructing wall question except now there are $2$ possible walls, and of different length, and  they can only appear in the middle mile (if at all).  I agree looking at the previous solutions to the other  question may be beneficial.

Comment: And one more comment: I really liked that other question. It had fewer arbitrary parameters than this one. Perhaps you could add some motivation why you're interested in this particular setup and not walls with arbitrary lengths and appearance probabilities?

Comment: When I wrote the previous question which was very well accepted by this math community, I was wondering what would happen if instead of just $1$ wall, there were $2$.  I was also wondering  what if we restrict the position of the walls to only be in the middle, not close to the endpoints.  I think if I made the parameters too flexible (such as any reasonable length wall at various probabilities to be there...), then it would be too confusing conceptually.  Here at least we know the lengths of the walls and where they might be (if present).  I think it makes for an interesting problem.

Comment: Also what makes this problem more interesting (to me) than the previous single wall problem is the interaction between the small and large walls.  A large wall followed quickly by a small wall will effectively make the small wall not even an obstruction (as if it was not even there).  An analogy would be a runner leaping over a large hurdle but there is also a smaller hurdle tucked in closely to the large hurdle.  By leaping over the large hurdle, the runner will also clear the smaller hurdle, however if the smaller hurdle was placed farther away, it could trip him up.

Comment: So math breaks down for a problem like this?  The 2nd wall throws a serious monkey wrench into it?  For simulation (which is one of the tags of this question),  it seems about the same complexity as the single wall but overall a more interesting problem to me.

Comment: Also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772096/optimization-with-a-probability/1772111#1772111 Why there are so many questions like these?

Comment: I don't know but mine was clearly posted first before this other one so perhaps the other one is a variation that was "lifted" from mine without giving me any credit for the idea.  Mine is a $2$ wall problem "appearing" with $2$ different probabilities so that (to me) makes it more interesting since there will be interactions between the walls but in different ways depending on which comes first, how close they are....  So far the best I have is still the simple caret shape which is upslope  of $0.5$ until mile $1$ then downslope of -$0.5$ directly to B.  That is the path if no walls present.

Comment: There is one potential ambiguity: suppose the big wall is the first to be encountered, and it happens before the halfway point. If you pass the small wall while you are still more than a half mile off center, are you aware of the event or do you have to proceed without knowing you have already passed both walls?

Comment: You only know of any wall if you bump it since it is like a force field.  If there is a "near miss" with a wall you won't know it.  It is not like a warning track in baseball when you are close to the  fence.  I am doing 2 types of simulation, one that has random walls and I just do a large amount of simulated walks such as $1$ million to get a reasonable average. The 2nd simulation I am doing is where I fix the $2$ wall positions in $1$ of $100$ equi-spaced spots each within the middle mile (thus $10,000$ combinations of $2$ wall positions), and then just take a weighted average of all walks.

Comment: @user5713492 -  So the answer to your question is no, near misses don't give you any more knowledge of the 2nd wall.  You wont know the difference of a near miss of the 2nd wall and the 2nd wall not even being there since from the walker's perspective, those should seem identical. I suppose computationally, if you knew you just passed the 2nd wall (and already cleared it), that could change the answer but it clearly states in the original question that you only know about any wall if you bump it.  Many interesting scenarios in this $2$ wall variation including small wall very soon after large.

Comment: Also, for anyone else simulating, the $2$ walls can be at the same exact position, in which case you can just treat it the same as only the large wall appearing.  It could also be the case that you encounter the small wall first , clear it, take a few steps and then bump the large wall.   Another interesting case is you encounter the small wall early and hope there is no large wall, but then very close to mile $1.5$ you encounter the large wall, creating a large detour and a steep negative slope back down to B.  Worst case if you try to walk directly from A to B is over $4$ miles ($2$ walls).

Comment: honestly, seeing as how a complete strategy consists of not only the curve that's followed when there is no wall, but ALSO all the curves you have to follow when you have found 1 wall and there is possibly another wall waiting behind (I haven't read anything in detail but i haven't seen any discussion about this point)  and as the problem with 1 invisible wall looked complicated enough (no closed form anything for the expected length), I really don't want to touch this problem.

Comment: I agree it is difficult to solve but unless I ask here, I might never be able to solve it. Perhaps together we can get close to solving it thru a combination of intense math and computer simulation. I wonder if there is any special software out there to help solve these types of minimum length problems. Also, if enough people tackled this, either in an advanced math class or an advanced computer simulation class (such as a graduate level), they might get it or get very close to optimal.   I can get a few slopes that are close to optimal but not the entire curve.  I suspect $2.6$ish is optimal.

Comment: I felt like I was close to getting the curve for the non-wall days, but after having reduced it to $2$ free parameters, something always goes wrong when I try to optimize them. Maybe my general path is wrong somehow. I'm going to keep on trying for a little bit, though.

Comment: Are you using Monte Carlo type simulation for the walls or are you forcing them to be at every position and at their exact probabilities cuz when I used Monte Carlo and tried to optimize  just a few flex points/slopes , I got inconsistent results cuz the random number generator was giving me different random numbers and thinking that some combination of points was optimal when in fact it was not cuz maybe during those runs I got an abnormally low number of large walls or something that shortened the average walk length significantly.

Comment: Try my simple slopes as I described in my answer as a starting point if all else fails and then try to wiggle those points/slopes to see if you can do better.  I don't think much better than $2.7$ miles can happen on average.

Comment: No Monte Carlo, just the variational principle and the Euler-Lagrange equations, just like what is shown in the partial solution below. I checked my math and it seems to be OK. The problem is really bloody if the natural path takes you outside the range of the small wall. I can see a problem: I didn't notice that you put a different lower probability on the small wall. I was assuming $50\%$ for both. Oh well, I was always getting marked down for not paying attention in class. It's a shame that you put so much complexity in all at once. A little bit at a time to find the limits...

Comment: Wow I only changed $2$ significant things which is I added a $2$nd smaller wall with a different probability and size than its bigger brother wall that is pretty much it.  The simulation code of this one vs. the previous uniwall question is only slightly more involved.  I have 2 different programs I use and they both seem to math up within a small amount of  variance which his normal (hey I think I made an unintended pun there).  It looks like the lower limit is around $2.7$ , probably high $2.6$s for absolute optimal cuz when I wiggle the $2.7$ numbers not much happens.

Comment: So maybe before you "dismiss" this variation as not adding anything new to mathematics, consider that just adding that one other wall went from a solvable solution, to an "ass kicker" problem.  Perhaps a graduate level class would really like to give this one a crack (pun intended).  Simulation on a fast computer would get it very close to optimal in a short amount of time.  The complexity to code this is not much at all.  Just find a few points/slopes and then semi fix those and  double the # of slopes points until you get an almost smooth curve at about $8$ to $16$  points/slopes.

Comment: I used an interpreted language which is like 2 orders of magnitude (100 times) slower than a real compiled general purpose language (such as c), but I was still able to get a decent (but suboptimal) solution thru perseverance.  Even after this bounty is awarded, I may continue to nip away at this, optimizing my program for speed by storing the partial path distance and referencing that and adding it to the part of the path that I wiggle, then I wont be recomputing the entire path length each time when only part of it is changing (the part closer to B).  That should speed things up a lot.

Comment: For example, if I have the first $1.25$ miles of slopes fixed and I am wiggling the last $1/4$ mile segment (tipping the slope), I can just record the partial pathlength from A to mile marker $1.25$ and keep referencing that instead of recomputing it.  Then I just add it to the distance of the last $1/4$ mile slope (including the cases where I hit a wall in that segment).  I would have to be careful that I don't upset any probabilities of wall encounters so it is a fair walk.  We are lucky we have relatively fast computers that can do billions of simulated walks in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer has been through so many revisions, but now I've gotten all the pieces completed and I am trying to make something readable out of it all. There are really $3$ main cases to deal with:
1. The path before any wall has been encountered
2. The path after the small wall but before the big wall
3. The path after the big wall but before the small wall.
Then the results of the $3$ parts can be combined to find an average distance walked.

## **Part 1**. The path before the first wall.

The big wall is present $50\%$ of the time, and it's uniformly distributed in $[\frac12,\frac32]$ when present. Thus the probability that the big wall has not been seen for $\frac12\le x\le\frac32$ is $P_b=\frac12+\frac12\left(\frac32-x\right)=\frac54-\frac12x$, and the small wall is only present $25\%$ of the time, so the same probability for the it is $P_s=\frac34+\frac14\left(\frac32-x\right)=\frac98-\frac14x$. So the probability that no walls have been encountered is $P_{bs}=P_bP_s=\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}$. Then the probability of the first wall being between $x$ and $x+dx$ is $P_{bs}(x)-P_{bs}(x+dx)=-\frac{dP_{bs}}{dx}dx=\left(-\frac14+\frac78x\right)dx$. We now compute the mean path length from the starting point to the first wall encountered, subtracting the distance to its center, or to the goal at $B$ if no wall is ever encountered. This is
$$\begin{align}\bar s=&\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left[\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_1)\right)^2}+\int_{\frac12}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx-y(x_2)\right]\left(-\frac14x_2+\frac78\right)dx_2+\\
&\frac38\left[\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_1)\right)^2}+\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1\left(+y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx+\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_3)\right)^2}\right]\tag{1}\end{align}$$
Where $x_1=\frac12$ and $x_3=\frac32$. Now we change order of integration as usual to get
$$\begin{align}&\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left(-\frac14x_2+\frac78\right)\int_{\frac12}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\,dx_2\\ \tag{2}
&=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}\int_{x}^{\frac32}\left(-\frac14x_2+\frac78\right)dx_2\,dx\\
&=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{33}{32}\right)dx\end{align}$$
Combining this with that $-y$ in the original integral and a similar integral from the part that took into account the contribution to the mean path length if no walls were present and the straight line parts, the path simplifies to
$$\begin{align}\bar s&=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left[\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}-\left(\frac78-\frac14x\right)y(x)\right]dx\\ \tag{3}
&+\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_1)\right)^2}+\frac38\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_3)\right)^2}\end{align}$$
The effect of a small deviation from the optimal path, $\delta y(x)$ is
$$\begin{align}\delta\bar s&=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left[\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\delta y^{\prime}(x)-\left(\frac78-\frac14x\right)\delta y(x)\right]dx\\
&+\frac{y(x_1)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_1)\right)^2}}\delta y(x_1)+\frac38\frac{y(x_3)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_3)\right)^2}}\delta y(x_3)\\
&=-\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left[\frac d{dx}\left\{\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right\}+\left(\frac78-\frac14x\right)\right]\delta y(x)dx\\
&+\left[\frac{y(x_1)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_1)\right)^2}}-\frac{y^{\prime}(x_1)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_1)\right)^2}}\right]\delta y(x_1)\tag{4}\\
&+\frac38\left[\frac{y(x_3)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y(x_3)\right)^2}}+\frac{y^{\prime}(x_3)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_3)\right)^2}}\right]\delta y(x_3)\end{align}$$
Since the variation in $\bar s$ must be invariant under small but arbitrary variations in path, the contents of each of the square brackets must be zero. The first line will yield the differential equation for the curved part of the path, and the second line has the solution
$$y^{\prime}(x_1)=2y(x_1)=\frac{y(x_1)-0}{\frac12-0}\tag{5}$$
Which shows that the first derivative is continuous across $x=\frac12$. The third line similarly has the solution
$$y^{\prime}(x_3)=-2y(x_3)=\frac{0-y(x_3)}{2-\frac32}\tag{6}$$
Which is the statement of continuity of the first derivative across $x=\frac32$.
Now back to that differential equation. We have an immediate integral which we can write as
$$\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}=\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)+\frac{1-c_1^2}{4}\tag{7}$$
We can solve for $y^{\prime}(x)$ to get
$$y^{\prime}=\frac{\left(\frac72-x\right)^2-c_1^2-(c_1^2-1)}{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sqrt{\left(\frac72-x\right)^2-c_1^2}}\tag{8}$$
Then we can substitute $\frac72-x=c_1\cosh\theta$ so this translates to
$$y^{\prime}=\frac{c_1^2\sinh^2\theta-(c_1^2-1)}{2c_1\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sinh\theta}=\frac{c_1^2\cosh^2\theta+1-2c_1^2}{2c_1\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sinh\theta}\tag{9}$$
Recalling that $dx=-c_1\sinh\theta\,d\theta$ we can integrate to get
$$\begin{align}y&=-\int\frac{c_1^2\sinh^2\theta-(c_1^2-1)}{2c_1\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sinh\theta}c_1\sinh\theta\,d\theta\tag{10}\\
=&\frac1{4\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}\left(-c_1^2\sinh\theta\cosh\theta+(3c_1^2-2)\theta\right)+c_2\end{align}$$
We can insert these expressions into the first derivative continuity conditions to get
$$\frac{10-2c_1^2}{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sqrt{9-c_1^2}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}\left(-3\sqrt{9-c_1^2}+(3c_1^2-2)\ln\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{9-c_1^2}}{c_1}\right)\right)+2c_2\tag{11}$$
$$\frac{5-2c_1^2}{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sqrt{4-c_1^2}}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}\left(-2\sqrt{4-c_1^2}+(3c_1^2-2)\ln\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{4-c_1^2}}{c_1}\right)\right)-2c_2\tag{12}$$
We can eliminate $c_2$ between these two equations so we only have one difficult equation to solve for $c_1$ with the result $c_1=1.814022405933661$ and $c_2=0.004495637179259$.
We have a relatively nice expression for
$$\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}=\frac{c_1^2\cosh^2\theta-1}{2c_1\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sinh\theta}\tag{13}$$
In terms of $\theta$.
With full knowledge of the curve in hand, from the continuity equations we have a simplified expression for the straight line path from $(0,0)$ to $\left(\frac12,y\left(\frac12\right)\right)$
$$\begin{align}L_1&=\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac12\right)\right)^2}=\frac12\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\left(\frac12\right)\right)^2}\tag{14}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sqrt{9-c_1^2}}=0.553038982525363\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}L_3&=\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}=\frac12\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\tag{15}\\
&=\frac3{4\sqrt{c_1^2-1}\sqrt{4-c_1^2}}=0.588379287212860\end{align}$$
We can integrate to find the curved part of the undisturbed path
$$\begin{align}L_{13}&=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_3}\frac{1-c_1^2\cosh^2\theta}{2\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}d\theta\\
&=\frac1{4\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}\left[3\sqrt{9-c_1^2}-2\sqrt{4-c_1^2}+(c_1^2-2)\ln\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{9-c_1^2}}{2+\sqrt{4-c_1^2}}\right)\right]\tag{16}\end{align}$$
Where $c_1\cosh\theta_1=3$ and $c_1\cosh\theta_3=2$. Since this works out to $L_{13}=1.042233793405411$, the total path length on a non-wall day will be $L_1+L_{13}+L_3=2.183652063143634$ miles.
The maximum excursion from the straight line path happens when $y^{\prime}=0$. This happens at $\theta_{\max}=0.759253746502349$, $x_{\max}=1.137510935801247$, and has a value of $y_{\max}=0.401134051668599$.
To get the average path length we have one more integral to evaluate
$$\begin{align}\bar s&=L_1+\frac38L_3+\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\left[\left(\frac18x^2-\frac78x+\frac{45}{32}\right)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}-\left(\frac78-\frac14x\right)y(x)\right]dx\\
&=\frac1{32\sqrt{c_1^2-1}}\left\{(-4c_1^2-2)\sqrt{4-c_1^2}+(-2c_1^4+15c_1^2-10)\ln\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{4-c_1^2}}{c_1}\right)\right.\\
&\left.+(6c_1^2+18)\sqrt{9-c_1^2}+(2c_1^4-30c_1^2+20)\ln\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{9-c_1^2}}{c_1}\right)\right\}\tag{17}\\
&-\frac58c_2+L_1+\frac38L_3=1.250510547155483=\text{Cost}_1\end{align}$$
This is the average length up to the first wall encountered, with the distance to the wall center subtracted, or to point $B$ if no wall was present.
I have included a graph of the path and a table for those who like discrete solutions.
[image: Figure 2]

$$\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\
0.000000&0.000000\\
0.500000&0.236331\\
0.540000&0.254769\\
0.580000&0.272258\\
0.620000&0.288778\\
0.660000&0.304305\\
0.700000&0.318815\\
0.740000&0.332282\\
0.780000&0.344676\\
0.820000&0.355965\\
0.860000&0.366113\\
0.900000&0.375080\\
0.940000&0.382821\\
0.980000&0.389287\\
1.020000&0.394421\\
1.060000&0.398157\\
1.100000&0.400423\\
1.140000&0.401131\\
1.180000&0.400180\\
1.220000&0.397452\\
1.260000&0.392800\\
1.300000&0.386048\\
1.340000&0.376976\\
1.380000&0.365301\\
1.420000&0.350650\\
1.460000&0.332511\\
1.500000&0.310145\\
2.000000&0.000000\\
\end{array}$$

## **Part 2**. The path after the small wall but before the big wall.

The probability of meeting the big wall between $x_2$ and $x_2+dx_2$ was $P(x_2)dx_2=\frac12dx_2$ at the outset, but the probability that we would get to $x_1$ without seeing the big wall was
$$P(x_1)=\frac12+\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}P(x_2)dx_2=\frac54-\frac12x_1\tag{18}$$
So the probability of meeting the big wall between $x_2$ and $x_2+dx_2$ given that we made it to $x_1$ without seeing it is
$$P(x_2|x_1)dx_2=\frac{P(x_2)}{P(x_1)}dx_2=\frac{2dx_2}{5-2x_1}\tag{19}$$
With this probability density function, we can assess the average cost of a given path $y(x)$ starting from $(x_1,0)$. It is
$$\begin{align}\bar s(x_1)&=\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left[\frac12+\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx+1-y(x_2)+\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+1}\right]\frac{2dx_2}{5-2x_1}\tag{20}\\
&+\left(1-\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\frac{2dx_2}{5-2x_1}\right)\left[\frac12+\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx+\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\right]\end{align}$$
The integral on the first line is to average the path length over all possible remaining positions of the big wall and the second line multiplies the probability of reaching $x_2=\frac32$ unscathed by the undisturbed (after hitting the small wall at $x_1$) path length to get the cost of the undisturbed path.
The first item in each of the square brackets is the $\frac12$ mile to get around the small wall because our accounting scheme subtracted our distance from the straight line path when the first wall was met.
The integral that comes next is the length of the curved part of our path up to $x_2$ where the big wall is or to $\frac32$ if the big wall leaves us alone.
If we meet the big wall, we will have to detour $1-y(x_2)$ but then we can go in a straight line from $(x_2,1)$ to $(2,0)$.
If no big wall, then after making it through the danger zone we can go straight from $(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right))$ to $(2,0)$. The probability of no big wall can be seen to be $\frac2{5-2x_1}$ and the cost contributed by the constants is
$$K_1=\frac12\left(\frac{3-2x_1}{5-2x_1}\right)+\left(\frac{3-2x_1}{5-2x_1}\right)+\frac12\left(\frac2{5-2x_1}\right)=\frac12+\frac{3-2x_1}{5-2x_1}\tag{21}$$
The average cost of all the straight line paths from the edge of the big wall to point $B$ is
$$\begin{align}K_2&=\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+1}dx_2\\
&=\frac2{5-2x_1}\left(-\frac12\right)\left[(2-x_2)\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+1}+\ln\left((2-x_2)+\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+1}\right)\right]_{x_1}^{\frac32}\tag{22}\\
&=\frac1{5-2x_1}\left[(2-x_1)\sqrt{(2-x_1)^2+1}+\ln\left((2-x_1)+\sqrt{(2-x_1)^2+1}\right)-\frac{\sqrt5}4-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\right)\right]\end{align}$$
The average cost of the curved path is
$$\begin{align}V_1&=\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\,dx_2+\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\\
&=\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}\int_{x}^{\frac32}dx_2\,dx+\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\\
&=\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left(\frac32-x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx+\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\\
&=\frac1{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left(5-2x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\tag{23}\end{align}$$
The average benefit of our path's deviation from the straight line path is
$$V_2=\frac2{5-2x_1}\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}-y(x)dx\tag{24}$$
And the average cost of the straight line part of the undisturbed path is
$$V_3=\frac2{5-2x_1}\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\tag{25}$$
The part of we can do something about by varying our path is
$$V_1+V_2+V_3=\frac1{5-2x_1}\left\{\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left[\left(5-2x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}-2y(x)\right]dx+2\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\right\}\tag{26}$$
We want our path to be invariant to first order to small changes to the path $\delta y$. The change in the contents of the curly braces above is
$$\begin{align}\delta V&=\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left[\left(5-2x\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\prime}}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}\delta y^{\prime}-2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y(x)\delta y\right]dx+\left[2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(x\right)\right)^2}\delta y\right]_{x=\frac32}\\
&=\left[\left(5-2x\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\delta y\right]_{x_i}^{\frac32}-\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left[\frac d{dx}\left(\left(5-2x\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right)+2\right]\delta ydx\tag{27}\\
&+\left[2\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(x\right)\right)^2}}\delta y\right]_{x=\frac32}\end{align}$$
Now, we know the value of $y(x_1)$, so $\delta y(x_1)=0$, but $y\left(\frac32\right)$ is free to wander so $\delta y\left(\frac32\right)$ can take on any value. Thus
$$\begin{align}\delta V&=\left[\frac{2y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}+\frac{2y\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}\right]\delta y\left(\frac32\right)\tag{28}\\
&-\int_{x_1}^{\frac32}\left[\frac d{dx}\left(\left(5-2x\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right)+2\right]\delta y(x)dx\end{align}$$
Since this has to be invariant to first order in $\delta y$, the contents of both sets of square brackets must be zero. The solution for the algebraic brackets is $y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)=-2y\left(\frac32\right)$. This has the physical significance that the slope of the path from $\left(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right)\right)$ to $(2,0)$ is
$$m=\frac{0-y\left(\frac32\right)}{2-\frac32}=-2y\left(\frac32\right)=y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)\tag{29}$$
This proves the continuity of the first derivative of the optimal path at the kink point $x=\frac32$. This was considered likely because there wasn't an obvious kink in the paths there, but it wasn't a given because light follows an optimal, too, but has kinks in its path where the refractive index of the medium changes discontinuously.
Now we have to solve the differential equation implied by the contents of the second set of square brackets.
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\left(5-2x\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right)=-2\tag{30}$$
This integrates to
$$\left(5-2x\right)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}=5-2x-2c_1^2\tag{31}$$
Solving for $y^{\prime}(x)$ and letting $u=5-2x-c_1^2$,
$$y^{\prime}(x)=\frac{5-2x-2c_1^2}{2c_1\sqrt{5-2x-c_1^2}}=\frac{u-c_1^2}{2c_1u^{1/2}}=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=-2\frac{dy}{du}\tag{32}$$
Integrating,
$$y=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u^{3/2}+c_1^2u^{1/2}\right)+c_2\tag{33}$$
At the start of the curved path,
$$y(x_1)=\frac12=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u_1^{3/2}+c_1^2u_1^{1/2}\right)+c_2\tag{34}$$
Where $u_1=u(x_1)=5-2x_1-c_1^2$. Then
$$y=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u^{3/2}+c_1^2u^{1/2}+\frac13u_1^{3/2}-c_1^2u_1^{1/2}\right)+\frac12\tag{35}$$
Our condition that determines $c_1$ is then
$$-2\left(\frac1{2c_1}\right)\left(u_3^{1/2}-c_1^2u_3^{-1/2}\right)=-2\left(\frac1{2c_1}\right)\left(-\frac13u_3^{3/2}+c_1^2u_3^{1/2}+\frac13u_1^{3/2}-c_1^2u_1^{1/2}\right)-1\tag{36}$$
Where $u_3=u\left(\frac32\right)=2-c_1^2$. Now, this equation is much easier to solve than was the case before I had proved continuity of the first derivative! With this value of $c_1$ in hand, we do the integral implied by $V_1+V_2$ to get
$$\begin{align}V_1+V_2&=-\frac12\left(\frac1{5-2x_1}\right)\left[\frac1{3c_1}u_3^{5/2}+c_1^3u_3^{1/2}\right.\tag{37}\\
&\left.-\frac1{3c_1}u_1^{3/2}u_3+c_1u_1^{1/2}u_3-c_1^3u_1^{1/2}-c_1u_1^{3/2}-u_3+u_1\right]\end{align}$$
Then we can compute $c_1(x_1)$ and $\text{Cost}_2(x_1)=K_1+K_2+V_1+V_2+V_3$ and tabulate some results and plot some paths.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}x_1&c_1&\text{Cost}_2(x_1)\\
0.5&1.2653039739&2.5451782877\\
0.6&1.2610954013&2.4328788766\\
0.7&1.2576330600&2.3174265702\\
0.8&1.2551457826&2.1983182953\\
0.9&1.2539248955&2.0749566112\\
1.0&1.2543450503&1.9466409733\\
1.1&1.2568937316&1.8125729376\\
1.2&1.2622157699&1.6719005163\\
1.3&1.2711914424&1.5238692094\\
1.4&1.2851258355&1.3682848227\\
1.5&1.3065629649&1.2071067812\\
\end{array}$$
[image: Figure 3]

Now we want the contribution to the total cost of this part of the path.
In part 1 that we separated the probability of not having encoutered a wall by $x_1$ into $P_{bs}(x_1)=P_b(x_1)P_s(x_1)$.
Then the probability of encountering any wall between $x_1$ and $x_1+dx_1$ is
$$-\frac{dP_{bs}}{dx_1}dx_1=-P_b\frac{dP_s}{dx_1}dx_1-P_s\frac{dP_b}{dx_1}dx_1\tag{38}$$
This separates the probability into probabilities that the small wall or big wall will be encountered, so the one we want is that for the small wall
$$-P_b\frac{dP_s}{dx_1}dx_1=\left(\frac54-\frac12x_1\right)\left(\frac14\right)dx_1=\frac1{16}(5-2x_1)dx_1\tag{39}$$
Then we multiply by $\text{Cost}_2(x_1)$ and integrate over the domain of the small wall to get
$$\text{Cost}_2=\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\text{Cost}_2(x_1)\frac{5-2x_1}{16}dx_1=0.374353894107649\tag{40}$$

## **Part 3**. The path after the big wall but before the small wall.

When starting out on our journey, the probability of finding the small wall between $x_3$ and $x_3+dx_3$ was $P(x_3)dx_3=\frac14dx_3$ because of its uniform distribution.
However, there was only a probability of $P(x_1)=\frac34+\frac14\left(\frac32-x_1\right)=\frac18(9-2x_1)$ of making it to $x=x_1$ without encountering the small wall between $x=\frac12$ and $x=x_1$,
so the probability of finding the small wall between $x_3$ and $x_3+dx_3$ given that we have made it to $x_1$ unscathed is
$$P(x_3|x_1)dx_3=\frac{P(x_3)dx_3}{P(x_1)}=\frac{2dx_3}{9-2x_1}\tag{41}$$
Now that we have the right probability distribution function, we can use it to find the mean distance to point $B$ given a path $y(x)$:
$$\begin{align}\bar s&=\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\left[1+\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+\frac14}+\int_{x_2}^{x_3}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\right.\tag{42}\\
&\left.+\frac12-y(x_3)+\sqrt{(2-x_3)^2+\frac14}\right]\frac{2dx_3}{9-2x_1}\\
&+\left(1-\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\frac{2dx_3}{9-2x_1}\right)\left[1+\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+\frac14}\right.\\
&\left.+\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx+\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\right]\end{align}$$
The integral on the first line above computes the contribution to the path length from days when the small wall was present.
The first $2$ terms are the width of the big wall, $1$ mile, and the straight-line path taken from the far edge of the big wall at $(x_1,1)$ down to where we are in danger of bumping the small wall at $(x_2,\frac12)$.
Then there is the length of the curved path up to where the small wall is at $(x_3,y(x_3))$, then the detour we must make around the small wall to $(x_3,\frac12)$ and then the straight line from there to point $B$ at $(2,0)$.
The stuff in the parentheses at the beginning of the second line is the probability that we would make it all the way through to $(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right))$ without the small wall being there,
$$P_{\text{undisturbed}}=1-\frac{3-2x_2}{9-2x_1}=\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\tag{43}$$
And then we have the $1$-mile detour around the big wall (recall that we subtracted $y(x_1)$ in part 1), the straight line from $(x_1,1)$ to $(x_2,\frac12)$, the length of the curved path from $(x_2,\frac12)$ to $(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right))$, and the straight line path from there to point $B$.
We can change the order of integration to simplify the arc length integral.
$$\begin{align}&\frac2{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\int_{x_2}^{x_3}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\,dx_3+\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\tag{44}\\
&=\frac2{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}\int_{x}^{\frac32}dx_3\,dx+\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\\
&=\frac1{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}(9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\end{align}$$
And that integral that represents the average straight line path from the small wall to point $B$ may be evaluated as
$$\begin{align}&\frac2{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{(2-x_3)^2+\frac14}dx_3=\frac2{9-2x_1}\int_{x_3=x_2}^{x_3=\frac32}-\frac14\cosh^2\theta\,d\theta\tag{45}\\
&=\frac1{9-2x_1}\left[(2-x_2)\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}\right.\\
&\left.+\frac14\ln\left(2-x_2+\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}\right)-\frac1{2\sqrt2}-\frac14\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt2}2\right)\right]\end{align}$$
The rest of the integral doens't vary in the interval of integration so we can add things up to
$$\begin{align}\bar s&=1+\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+\frac14}+\frac12\left(\frac{3-2x_2}{9-2x_1}\right)+\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\tag{46}\\
&+\frac1{9-2x_1}\left[(2-x_2)\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}\right.\\
&\left.+\frac14\ln\left(2-x_2+\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}\right)-\frac1{2\sqrt2}-\frac14\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt2}2\right)\right]\\
&+\frac1{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\left[(9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}-2y(x)\right]dx\end{align}$$
Now that we have the length expressed so simply in term of the path $y(x)$ we will apply a variation $y(x)+\delta y(x)$ and make the dependence on $\delta y(x)$ vanish to first order.
$$\begin{align}&\delta\frac1{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\left[(9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}-2y(x)\right]dx\tag{47}\\
&=\frac1{9-2x_1}\left[(6-2x_1+2x_2)\frac{y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}\delta y\left(\frac32\right)-(9-2x_1)\frac{y^{\prime}(x_2)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_2)\right)^2}}\delta y(x_2)\right]\\
&-\frac1{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\left[\frac d{dx}\left((9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right)\delta y(x)+2\delta y(x)\right]dx\end{align}$$
The integrand above must vanish for any small variation $\delta y(x)$ so in due course that will give us a differential equation for the path but we don't know the values of the endpoints $(x_2,\frac12)$ and $(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right))$ so we have to take into account how the rest of the terms in $\bar s$ vary with the path.
The right endpoint is relatively simple
$$\delta\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}=\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\frac{y\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}\delta y\left(\frac32\right)\tag{48}$$
(Neglecting for the moment the dependence on $x_2$) Combining with  the $\delta y\left(\frac32\right)$ term from integration by parts and considering that the variation must be invariant to first order in $\delta y$,
$$\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\frac{y\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}+\frac{6-2x_1+2x_2}{9-2x_1}\frac{y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}}=0\tag{49}$$
The solution is $$y^{\prime}\left(\frac32\right)=-2y\left(\frac32\right)\tag{50}$$
Since that is the slope of the line from $\left(\frac32,y\left(\frac32\right)\right)$ to $(2,0)$ this demonstrates the continuity of the first derivative at the right endpoint. The left endpoint is messier. As the path $y(x)$ varies it moves the left endpoint around because $y(x_2)=y(x_2+\delta x_2)+\delta y(x_2)=y(x_2)+y^{\prime}(x_2)\delta x_2+\delta y(x_2)=\frac12$ is fixed. Thus
$$\delta x_2=-\frac{\delta y(x_2)}{y^{\prime}(x_2)}\tag{51}$$
So we have to differentiate $\bar s$ with respect to $x_2$, including the lower bound of the integral via the fundamental theorem of calculus, divide by $y^{\prime}(x_2)$, and subtract from the term we got from the lower limit from integration by parts to get
$$\begin{align}0&=-\frac{y^{\prime}(x_2)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_2)\right)^2}}-\frac1{y^{\prime}(x_2)}\left[\frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+\frac14}}-\frac1{9-2x_1}+\frac2{9-2x_1}\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}\right.\\
&\left.-\frac2{9-2x_1}\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}-\frac1{9-2x_1}\left\{(9-2x_1)\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_2)\right)^2}-2y(x_2)\right\}\right.\tag{52}\\
&\left.+\frac2{9-2x_1}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\right]\end{align}$$
Not pretty but it cleans up to
$$\begin{align}&\frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+\frac14}}-\frac1{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x_2)\right)^2}}\tag{53}\\
&=\frac2{9-2x_1}\left[\sqrt{(2-x_2)^2+\frac14}-\sqrt{\frac14+\left(y\left(\frac32\right)\right)^2}-\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx\right]\end{align}$$
The left hand side can be recognized as the difference between $\sin\theta_i-\sin\theta_r$, so there is refraction at this boundary!
Now we can get back to the differential equation for the path $y(x)$. We had
$$\frac d{dx}\left((9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}\right)=-2\tag{54}$$
We can integrate to
$$(9-2x_1+2x_2-2x)\frac{y^{\prime}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}}=9-2x_1+2x_2-2x-2c_1^2\tag{55}$$
Solving for $y^{\prime}(x)$,
$$y^{\prime}(x)=\frac{9-2x_1+2x_2-2x-2c_1^2}{2c_1\sqrt{9-2x_1+2x_2-2x-c_1^2}}=\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{u-c_1^2}{2c_1u^{1/2}}\tag{56}$$
Where we have made the substitution $u=9-2x_1+2x_2-2x-c_1^2$, $u_2=u(x_2)=9-2x_1-c_1^2$, and $u_4=u\left(\frac32\right)=6-2x_1+2x_2-c_1^2$. We can integrate this to get
$$y=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u^{3/2}+c_1^2u^{1/2}\right)+c_2\tag{57}$$
We know that
$$y(x_2)=\frac12=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u_2^{3/2}+c_1^2u_2^{1/2}\right)+c_2\tag{58}$$
So we have our path
$$y=\frac1{2c_1}\left(-\frac13u^{3/2}+c_1^2u^{1/2}+\frac13u_2^{3/2}-c_1^2u_2^{1/2}\right)+\frac12\tag{59}$$
To solve for $c_1$ and $x_2$ first we have to evaluate that integral
$$\begin{align}\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\sqrt{1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}dx&=\int_{x_2}^{\frac32}\frac1{2c_1}\left[u^{1/2}+c_1^2u^{-1/2}\right]\left(\frac{-du}{2}\right)\tag{60}\\
&=\frac1{2c_1}\left[\frac13u_2^{3/2}+c_1^2u_2^{1/2}-\frac13u_4^{3/2}-c_1^2u_4^{1/2}\right]\end{align}$$
So now we can put everything in the equations for continuity of the first derivative at the right endpoint and our version of Snell's law at the left endpoint and solve for $c_1$ and $x_2$. Then we have paths plotted in the large and in detail.
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 4]

Even in the closeup it's pretty much impossible to see the refraction at $y=\frac12$.
We can then evaluate the integral we optimized with such difficulty and find the cost of each path. Here is a table.
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}x_1&c_1&x_2&y\left(\frac32\right)&\text{Cost}_3(x_1)\\
0.5&2.4687532134&1.3131625215&0.3733857985&2.8090608793\\
0.6&2.4622847219&1.3501274970&0.3917097193&2.7249375529\\
0.7&2.4566369485&1.3874433837&0.4127942541&2.6429339266\\
0.8&2.4518060881&1.4249923978&0.4372691891&2.5634550764\\
0.9&2.4477477457&1.4625992592&0.4659645229&2.4870044450\\
1.0&2.4443554844&1.5000000000&0.5000000000&2.4142135624\\
1.1&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&2.3453624047\\
1.2&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&2.2806248475\\
1.3&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&2.2206555616\\
1.4&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&2.1661903790\\
1.5&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&\unicode{x2014}&2.1180339887\\
\end{array}$$
If $1\le x_1\le\frac32$, there was no interference from the small wall because the straight line path to $B$ went around $\left(\frac32,\frac12\right)$.
To get the cost we multiply by the probability of encountering the big wall first at $x_1$, which from our analysis of parts 1 and 2 is
$$-P_s\frac{dP_b}{dx_1}dx_1=\left(\frac98-\frac14x_1\right)\left(\frac12\right)dx_1=\frac1{16}(9-2x_1)dx_1\tag{61}$$
And integrate over the domain of the big wall to get
$$\begin{align}\text{Cost}_3&=\int_{\frac12}^1\text{Cost}_3(x_1)\frac{9-2x_1}{16}dx_1+\int_1^{\frac32}\left[1+\sqrt{(2-x_1)^2+1}\right]\frac{9-2x_1}{16}dx_1\tag{62}\\
&=0.611754747093525+0.458894932339652=1.070649679433177\end{align}$$
And we can add up the contributions to the total cost from each of the parts to get
$$\begin{align}\text{Cost}&=\text{Cost}_1+\text{Cost}_2+\text{Cost}_3\\ \tag{63}
&=1.250510547155483+0.374353894107649+1.070649679433177\\
&=2.695514120696309\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow it appears you put a lot of effort into this already and it is interesting how that 2nd wall makes it much harder to solve.  Perhaps I should re-post this same question in a computer simulation site and see if anyone can beat the $2.7$ mile or so that I got with just a simple shape.   I would have to think very hard about an algorithm to  do many walks and to find a near optimal one.  Guessing got my started but I doubt anyone can guess the absolute optimal path.  I will look at this more when I have some free time tonight to play with it and at least get some simple path that beats $2.7$.

Comment: User5713492 - Is there any "simple" code you could "whip up" in the next $8$ hours that would help find the general shape of the entire curve?  Perhaps just a few points/slopes such as $3$ or $4$?    The bounty will be up in about $8$ hours but they may have a $24$ hour extension but I am not sure.  I will try to write more code tonight too.  The best I got so far is about $2.7$ miles average walk distance using Monte Carlo technique with limited ranges on the $3$ or $4$ slopes.  I suspect optimal will be around $2.6$ish, perhaps into the high $2.5$s.  Good luck to all that try to solve this.

Comment: Well, I tried the optimization as discussed in my post. Worked out the gradient and Hessian of that function and wrote it up in about $30$ .m files, but it failed to converge. There is so much code in there that it's impossible to check to find out what's going wrong so I am toast. I've got work coming up in a little while, too. Have you tried checking the equations I posted?

Comment: user5713492 - Can you get a curve anything like mine?  I just used a brute force simulation method in multiple stages of precision.  I haven't yet played with the slope in the initial half mile which may help things but for a fixed slope there, about $0.5$ slope seems about optimal so far.  That slope will put us at about ($0.5, 0.25$) which is shown on my graph.

Comment: I'm making some progress on the initial part of the curve. Got to sleep now, though. Hope I can get something printable in the morning.

Comment: The bounty will be up in about 1 hour so I will award it to you since you gave this problem the most effort, even though you didn't quite solve it totally.  I did however say I would award $150$ bounty points so it is fair that you are only getting $100$ since it appears to be about a $2/3$rds solution at this point but I encourage you to keep going even after the bounty as I will do more simulation too to get it faster.  The mental stimulation of something like this is worth the time it help keeps your brain exercised and sharp and for me it helps keep my programming skills decent.  Thanks!

Comment: I awarded you the bounty of $100$ points thank you for your efforts!.  If you can get the optimal solution I will give you the checkmark too and you will have the glory of being the only person here to solve it and post the answer.  I think if you get about $2.69$ miles or something close to that it can be considered optimal based on my simulation which seems to be bottoming out at about $2.7$.

Comment: Try to finish your work please.  Perhaps break it into specific cases such as small wall only , large wall only... and then just combine the partial answers using their proper probabilities.  This is what I did with one of my simulations.  I looped thru all the possible wall positions, walking all $999$ of them.      I then took the average (since they are all the same likelihood) and weighted it properly according to how likely that case would occur.  I imagine the math could be somewhat analogous to the simulation in that it could somehow just integrate the same thing I count up discretely.

Comment: I am still waiting for a final curve of the entire solution from you so we could compare it to my rough curve.  I think  anything I do in simulation on this can also be done using math cuz I am just breaking it into several cases and doing the walk and then just taking a weighted average at the end.   I guess the hardest part is knowing what y value to be at at each point in the walk for the optimal solution.  However, it should be clear that from starting point A, we need to go up (or down) at least a little bit and then somewhere past the midpoint (mile $1$) head back towards B.

Comment: You can see my curve for the initial path. There isn't only one curve for the part of the path after the first wall was encountered, because the starting points are all different. Look at my 'Optimal path near far corner' graph (which solves the wrong problem and must be fixed) and see that there isn't just one path from that point. Have made progress on continuity of first derivative. No longer worried about matching your results which are all over the place. Your path isn't straight outside danger zone so it's wrong. Fix you graph, too. Maybe I'll have enough energy today.

Comment: How are my results all over the place?  I pick a path and tell the average distance.  I started with a very simple path, always trying to go directly at B unless there is a wall to go around first.  That path was about $2.8$ miles.  Then I introduced slopes and I did better.  I had my simulation program walk millions of paths and  I plotted my best path so far.  What do you mean my path is not outside the danger zone?  We are just trying to minimize the average walk distance, not circumvent the walls.  The optimal path will likely hit walls often but will already be part of the way up them.

Comment: Also it is not easy for me to make a new graph cuz my mouse is messed up and it makes it  difficult to crop images to get them the way I like.   My solution is a full solution, handling all cases (no walls,  either wall, or both walls in  both orders).  It averages everything together properly and gives a final walk distance.  Best I got so far is about $2.7$ miles on average.  This also includes the  bad cases like the small wall close to $0.5$ and the large wall close to $1.5$.  Everything is accounted for as far as I know.

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to make a mistake when the algorithm used is a simple one like mine. I basically break the walk in many cases (no walls, small wall only, large wall only, small b4 large, large b4 small).  I walk them all, keeping track of the average walk length for each, then I simply take a weighted average of them to get the overall average walk length.  I even took that program and set all the slopes at $0$ (thus always trying to walk towards B when there are no walls), and I got the correct $2.8$ miles as my other program that was hardcoded to always walk towards B.

Comment: All over the place means you were 0.340 at the 1.25 mile mark before and now you are at 0.425. Also, you went from $(0,0)$ to $(0.25,0.125)$ to $(0.5,0.275)$ for a cost of $0.279508+0.291548=0.571056$. For what reason didn't do that in one step for a cost of $0.570636$? You can be quite a ways from the optimal path yet still be close to the optimal cost. I still intend to go forward even though I haven't posted anything in a couple of days. It's moving day for undergraduates, so you could dumpster dive a whole computer, let alone a mouse, at your nearest campus!

Comment: One reason I cannot get precise y values is cuz my programming environment is too slow (it is interpreted not compiled).   If I used my algorithm in a language like compiled c instead, I could get very precise slopes probably to the hundredth of a mile.  Instead I have to just settle for lower precision.  For example, my first pass of the algorithm, I run the wiggle points/slopes at $0.1, 0.2...1.0$ to  find the approximate slope of the first $1/2$ mile segment.   Once I know optimal is close to $0.5$, then I go back and edit my code to loop from $0.4$ to $0.6$ in $0.05$ steps....

Comment: Best I can do short term is to let the program run for a few days and while that is running, work on my 3rd version of the program which will  remember the distance so far as it wiggles points past that.  For example, if I have $6$ wiggle points but the loop is at the 4th point, it can just remember to cost/distance up to that point and just compute the cost/distance after that.  That should save some computational time and allow me to run more iterations of the nested loops, thus being able to get more accurate points/slopes.

Comment: Any progress on a final graph containing all possible cases of walls?  I am working on my 3rd version of a simulation program but trying to get it to run very fast compared to the other previous versions.  When I get some results I will post them.  To keep things simpler at first, I am only using $2$ slopes, an upslope of $0.375$ the first mile then a downslope of $-0.375$ the 2nd mile.  I may try to hold the upslope a little longer than $1$ mile to see if that helps any and of course steepen the downslope.  Even with just $2$ slopes, it is an interesting problem to figure out optimally.

Comment: Wow impressive work.  This problem is harder than the single wall problem  cuz of the $5$ or so subcases.  It is kinda like solving $5$ subproblems and then combining the results in the proper proportion.  That is basically what my simulation does.  For example, one of those five  subproblems is to walk all possible small wall only positions (from $0.501$ to $1.499$) using some "simplified" path such as only $2$ or $4$ differently sloped segments.  In my case I am only using $2$ slopes initially which are $0.375$ the first mile and $-0.375$ the 2nd mile.

Comment: Wow.  So much work mathematically to get optimal when near optimal can be had for probably 1/100th of the effort.  This guy should be commended for his persistence.  This is a ton of work to get the optimal path but he didn't give up.  I am tempted to  start a 2nd bounty and just award it to him but the minimum I can do is 200 since I already had a 1st bounty he got for 100.  This work is worth WAY more than 100 points.  I will figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

I like to approach this kind of problem by first looking at worst cases, then see where I can make improvements.  first I assume that there is only the small wall present, located anywhere in the middle mile.  Starting at point A, I walk toward point B, but at an angle of 45deg to the right (one could have gone left instead) until I reach the point where I have walked 1/2 mile ahead and 1/2 mile to the right, a distance of .707 miles.  I am now at the outside edge of the right side of the small wall.  Now I walk straight ahead, parallel to the AB line for 1 mile.  I will not encounter any small wall because I am just to the right of it.  After I finish that mile, I will walk toward point B, which is .707 miles away, giving a total walk distance of 2.414 miles, and this will work every day there is no big wall, i.e. 50 % of the time. 
Now to account for the big wall.  I will start again as described above by walking at a 45deg angle to the right for .707 miles.  I then again begin to walk straight ahead parallel to the AB line, but now I might hit the big wall on my next step, or anywhere in the next mile.  It will make a difference in my walk if I hit the big wall in the first 1/2 mile or the last 1/2 mile.  Lets start with the big wall being in the first 1/2 mile, and call the distance "x" to the wall from where I started walking parallel to line AB, where x is measured in miles and has a value between 0 and 1 inclusive.  Once I hit the big wall at distance x, I begin walking along the wall toward the right, and go 0.5 miles to reach it's end.  Now I walk in the direction of B but again parallel to the AB line.  When I reach a point half way through the middle mile (if I am not there already), I can see point B directly, whether or not there is a small wall ahead, and I then walk directly toward B, a distance of 1.414 miles.  Here the total walk is .707 + x + .5 + (.5 - x) + 1.414 = 3.121 miles.
This answer is getting too long, so let me just say the worst case walk when the wall is in the last 1/2 of the middle mile is 3.325 miles.  Taking the two results for the big wall case, we have an average value for walk time with the big wall, with or without the small wall present, of about 3.223 miles, and will occur about 50% of the time.
RESULT:  I would take the first described walk every day, and if I ran into a big wall, I would modify my course as shown in the second described walk.  My average distance would be (2.414 + 3.223)/2 = 2.818 miles.  I make no claim that this number is the optimal solution, as other possibilities may yield slightly better results, but the effort is not worth the improvement.

Comment: $2,818$ is decent but not as good as the walk directly at B method I described as my "base case" solution.  Also, worst case is when the small wall comes early (very close to mile marker $0.5$) and the large wall comes late (very close to mile marker $1.5$), however, luckily, that doesn't happen often.  Also remember $3$ out of every $8$ walk days (on average) there are no walls, so it makes sense not to stray too far from the direct AB line for the optimal solution.  This strategy seems pretty good and makes sense but I am somewhat surprised it is not better than about $2.818$.

Comment: One place where this method is somewhat flawed is that  you immediately go up to y=$0.5$ at a $45$ degree angle so you will be at point ($0.5$,  $0.5$).  Then you hold y=$0.5$ from  ($0.5$, $0.5$) to ($1.5$ , $0.5$) if no large wall is present.  This is decent except that you wont be able to tell the difference between small wall only days and no walls days this way.  It might be better to hold y=$0.49$ so you will  bump into the small wall if it is there, then you have more information and can maybe arc down as you pass the $1$ mile marker since the chances of another wall are diminishing.

Comment: To me, logically, it seems that any walk path that "holds flat" for more than just a very short segment cannot be optimal since it is not adjusting for the fact that as you increase your x position, you are less likely to see any walls.  Holding flat at  y=$0.5$ is a good "first effort" solution, but can easily be beat.  I somehow feel that y=$0.5$ is part of the optimal solution as  it may be somewhat of a "magic number" in that it clears the small walls and is halfway up the  large wall so I can guess with some confidence that the  optimal solution never has y going much above about $0.5$.

Comment: I have to commend this solution even though it is not optimal cuz of its simplicity.  The effort to quality answer ratio is high on this one cuz the effort is so low (kinda like my attempt to always walk directly at B solution which is about the same average walk distance as this).  However, I think this estimate is too high since you cannot just average a few endpoint cases, you have to integrate perhaps $1000$ possible wall positions per mile otherwise your results will not be accurate.  If I crank down my # of wall slices I see this in my program output (but it runs a lot quicker).

Comment: Hi David:  Thanks for your thoughtful comments, and I agree with most of them.  One little surprise in my method, and perhaps your "always head for B method" is that it is reversible.  The way I set up my walk, you can retrace your steps from B to A , getting again an average walk distance of 2.818.  In that case, we have the small wall first at .5 miles, and the large wall at 1.5 miles when x =0 as originally defined.

Comment: Ok but for me it is simpler to walk from A to B and consider what obstacles I may have along the way and where I should be in anticipation of them. In my Monte Carlo type simulation, I maintain a variable called pdsf which stands for path distance so far.  My walk path is basically a bunch of short hypotenuses, some of which are collinear with the previous ones cuz they share the same slope. However, by using slopes, it make it easier to code the program cuz then I can just pick $3$ slope segments (the first $3$ half mile segments) and tip them to see how they affect the overall walk distance.

Comment: If I had a super fast computer and a compiled language (not interpreted like I use which is MUCH slower), I could tip many slopes such as $10$ or more and get a good approximation of the optimal curve.  In theory this would work simply by walking millions of paths and just picking the best.  This involves very little math but would in theory almost match the best mathematical solution.  Since computers are not infinitely fast, some clever algorithm could be used such as remembering previously walked partial paths (perhaps indexing them with the slopes thus far).  This problem is solvable!

Comment: I simulated this strategy using my Monte Carlo type approach for $100,000 $ walks and $1000$ possible wall positions for each wall each walk and I get $2.77438$ miles on average.  This is actually not bad for a first effort and it actually beats the straight at B approach which is about $2.8$.  Runtime to check this on my simple (no attempt was made to optimize for speed) interpreted code is about $4$ minutes.  If you made one minor change which is to slope up to and hold ($0.5, 0.25$) instead of ($0.5, 0.5$) until x=$1.5$, then the average walk distance drops to $2.7281$ which is significant.

Comment: It should be apparent that holding y=$0.5$ is not optimal cuz the small wall appears only $25$% of the time so going over them all will push you out of the way $75$% of the time for the small wall only case.  Fortunately being at y=$0.5$ helps anticipate the large wall but it is still too high as it appears the optimal curve never goes that high, perhaps peaking around y=$0.375$.  Decent walk strategy though and it did beat the direct at B strategy and your crude estimation was ballpark so I would say it is a partial success.  Sometimes I appreciate the "cutting corners" approach.

Comment: I am pretty much done with this problem as the results are pretty much what I expected.  $2.68$ miles seems about right as optimal.  The shape of the non wall day curve is not much different than that of the simpler single wall problem.  The amazing thing to me about this problem is how close the super simple path of $0.375$ upslope then -$0.375$ downslope is to optimal at about $2.72$ miles.  As I stated before, this is an excellent yet super simple guess based on the fact it is the average height of the $2$ walls.  I bet if I were to tweak the $2$ slopes I can do even better that $2.72$.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently designing another (3rd) simulation which will be "smarter" in that as it "wiggles" points/slopes, it will remember the partial path length up to that point and just compute the remainder of the path. This will likely speed up the simulation and allow me to use more iterations of the random walls to get a better average.  This is a "balancing act" between speed and accuracy.  What I can do during the day is reduce the accuracy so I can get a good idea of      the ballpark points/slopes, then highly restrict those points/slopes and increase the precision/accuracy and let it run overnight.  I should be able to get $8$ or so accurate slopes/points and that should be about $99$% of optimal I would think.  If someone beats me by say $0.01$ or $0.02$ miles (about $50$ to $100$ feet), I wont feel so bad for my solution and will congratulate them on their effort..

Someone with a fast computer should be easily able to simulate this and come up with about $8$ points/slopes rather easily.  I've given you by best solution so far so someone could take that and fine tune it even more.  This is not a hard program at all to write it is rather easy which is why I am surprised that someone didn't just write a program to do millions or even billions of simulated walks and just pick the best.  Just "wiggle" about $8$ points/slopes and you pretty much got it.  The curved walk path solution wont be much better than that, perhaps $0.01$ or $0.02$ miles shorter but that is only about $50$ to $100$ feet shorter so negligible.  I say this based on the solution to the previous (easier) related problem with only $1$ obstructing wall.  I was able to very closely approximate that optimal curve with only $8$ well chosen slopes.

However, I am somewhat amazed at how close to optimal the super simple solution of $4$ symmetrical slopes produces: $0.5$, $0.25$, $-0.25$, and $-0.5$, each cover half a mile.  This maxes out y at $0.375$.  An even simpler path would be a caret (^) shape with symmetric slopes of $0.375$ and $-0.375$, each one mile long.

Simple $2$ slope solution is about $2.72$ miles.
Simple $4$ slope solution is about $2.71$ miles.

Following this pattern I suspect $8$ slopes would be about $2.70$ miles and $16$ slopes would be about $2.69$ miles.  I doubt an optimal curve would be much better than about $2.68$ miles.

I am currently running a simulation program overnight that is estimated to take about $10$ hours to complete.  It has $6$ wiggle points.  I will post the hopefully better solution as soon as I get it (in about $10$ more hours).  If my programming environment was compiled instead of interpreted, I could probably get my answer in a few minutes rather than many hours.  Even only a small fraction of the way thru, I am already seeing a path of about $2.6989$ miles ($1/4$ miles slopes of $.5,~.6,~.4,~.3,~-.1,~-.4,~-.65,~-.65$).  I don't have the proper setup to be able to wiggle these points effectively so someone else should try many points close to these to see if a marginal improvement is possible.

Unless I can rewrite my simulation program to run MUCH faster, there is not much more I can do with this.  I was hoping someone would just do a simulation and get maybe 8 points/slopes to approximate a curve and I would be happy with that since it should be close to optimal if the points/slopes are good ones.

I am making some progress on this.  I will take the case of the small wall only first and try to make it very fast.  Then with that working well, the other cases are somewhat similar.  Initially (for simplicity), I will only have $2$ slopes (likely $0.375$ and $-0.375$, each $1$ mile long.  If I build this thing up carefully and slowly so that I have a very good grasp on it, I should be able to make it fast enough so I can wiggle many points and it should run in a reasonable amount of time.

Actually, it seems like a proper answer to this question would not only show the non wall day walk path (likely a curve to be optimal), but also explain what you would do to "recover" when you hit a wall (or walls).  For example, if only the large wall is present, you will not walk the curvy path as when no wall is present.  But just saying you go around the wall seems insufficient cuz then what do you do after that?  Do you try to go back to your curvy (no wall) path?  Do you make a beeline for point B?  Is your strategy different for small wall hit first vs. large wall hit first?  I am beginning to think this problem may not be solvable cuz of the myriad of possible "recovery" paths.

How would someone know if aiming directly at B once clearing a wall is optimal or not?  I would think it depends on whether it is the small wall or large wall and where encountered.  I am thinking always pointing towards B immediately after a wall encounter is not optimal unless it is the 2nd wall encountered on a particular walk.

Comment: I'll be printing out my simulation code tonight and going thru it with a fine tooth comb and getting an exact solution for the simple $2$ slope method to help verify my results from my other more flexible (but Monte Carlo style) simulation code.  This newer code walks all $999$ possible single wall position cases (separate $999$ walks for small wall and large wall only cases). Also, $998,001$ walks "all" possible $2$ wall positions (using $0.001$ wall increments and accounting for $999$ cases where $2$ walls are in the same exact position). Should be interesting and I will try to post tonight.

Comment: I hope to get as close to optimal with as simple a solution as possible. If you look at the curve submitted by user5713492,  it can be roughly approximated by an upslope of $0.375$ the first mile then a downslope of $-0.375$ the 2nd mile.  Once I get those slopes working in my code, I will play with them slightly like holding the first slope until x=$1.1$ and slightly steepening the downslope the last $0.9$ miles (perhaps $-.45833$ slope). The simulation code I have so far (not done) seems fairly fast in that it can do over 1 million walks in about $1.5$ seconds (at $0.001 wall increments).

Comment: Also, another fun simulation method to try (since the discreet number of possible wall position combinations is reasonable = about 1 million total), is to use a combination of Monte Carlo (random) style for the first $90$% or so (preventing any duplicates), then use a table of non-seen wall position combinations to fill in the missing ones. That way you will walk all of the possible paths and get a fair average and wont get different results each run. This may be good for someone that started with a Monte Carlo type simulation and wants it to be exact each time, not at the mercy of randomness.

Comment: The 3rd simulation is more difficult than I thought it would be.  The problem is if I want to hold a slope of say $0.375$ the first mile, I now have to decide what slope do I take if I encounter a wall (let's say the small wall) at mile $0.75$ for example.  The points I hit would be $(.5, ,1875), (.75, .28125), (.75, .5)$.  Then the question is where do I go next?  Do I slope down to B after encountering the first (and possibly only) wall, or do I slope to where I would have been had I not encountered any wall within the first mile?  I haven't yet decided so I need to do more analysis.

Comment: I've made it through the whole process at last. I'll write up changes in the initial path (calculations only, results are the same) when I get time.
Cost 0.0-2.0 = 1.250510547155483 Initial path
Cost 0.5-1.0 = 0.598526786129468 Big wall first half
Cost 1.0-1.5 = 0.423913382289695 Big wall second half
Cost 0.5-1.5 = 0.409796449203588 Small wall
Total cost = 2.682747164778234 Sum of above

Comment: Wow this is impressive work and in line with my prediction that the optimal solution would not be much better than $2.68$.  This was the pattern I was seeing as I doubled the # of points/slopes from $2$ ($2.72$ cost) to $4$ ($2.71$ cost), then I extrapolated to $2.70$ cost for $8$ points/slopes and $2.69$ cost for $16$ points/slopes and  suspected the  cost would bottom out around $2.68$.  Some simple simulation shows that even the simple path of $.375$ slope 1st mile then $-.375$ slope 2nd mile is a darn good path at about $2.72$ miles.  I could optimize that further and get less cost.

Comment: If found another mistake and the cost is now up to 2.69551. Hopefully my solution is now better organized and more readable.

Comment: Awesome work buddy.  Your results seems to match my simulation.  The best I got was in the high 2.69s so you slightly beat me.  A good variation to this problem would be if you could only change directions once on a non-wall day what would be the optimal path.  Don't solve it just think about it.  I bet if I held my caret shaped path a little longer than to mile 1.0 (perhaps to mile 1.1) and tweaked the y value from 0.375 to maybe something a bit higher, I could approach 2.7 miles with only a very simple path.

Answer (score -2):

Since I am not very mathematically inclined, I can only do computer simulation to first try simple paths, then slowly try more sophisticated paths.  My computer simulation will just pick $2$ random positions for the walls if they are present based on their probabilities.  There are $5$ main cases to handle for this problem... $1$) no wall, $2$) small wall only, $3$) large wall only, $4$) small wall before large wall, $5$) large wall before small wall.  I will be doing a simulation of this breaking it into these $5$ cases.

Also, if you attempt to always walk directly at B (except when you are walking around a wall) and both walls are present, I calculated (by hand) that the worst case with the small wall close to $0.5$ mile marker and large wall close to $1.5$ mile marker causes a walk distance of about $4.1$ miles.  (someone please check this).  The $5$ walks segments lengths (in order) are: $.5$, $.25$, $1.275$, $.958$, $1.118$ for a total of $4.101$ miles (more than double the direct path when no walls are present).

Also worth mentioning is the "pessimistic path" which circumvents the walls in all cases by using a slope of $2$ in the first half mile, holding y=$1$ for the middle mile, the dropping back down to B with a slope of $-2$.  This path is about $3.24$ miles.

Slightly better than this "pessimistic path" might be to instead hold y=$0.99$ instead of y=$1$, so that if the large wall is encountered, we will know where it is and can then adjust our path more directly towards B.

Another possible strategy is to "play the probabilities".  It would involve  figuring out what is the chance of the large wall showing up first, and then aiming up that percentage of its uplength.  Problem is you don't know where it will be until you hit it so maybe pick the middle spot of mile marker $1$ initially and see what happens.  That is, from A, immediately slope up to (1, P(large wall encountered first)).  Both units being in miles.  This will almost certainly not be optimal but is a decent strategy for simulation cuz it is simple and it considers the larger wall.

Another "simple" strategy is to figure out a good slope for the extremes (large wall at mile $0.51$ and large wall at mile $1.49$ and pick some intermediate slope.  I doubt that would go much above y=$0.5$.

If someone has a possible solution to a minimal walk path but doesn't want to type in all of their solution cuz it is time consuming, just enter a table of x,y values from x = $0$ to $2$ in $0.1$ steps.

$UPDATE~~1$ - I wrote the simulation program for the simple strategy that always tries to walk directly towards B but still having to go around any walls.  I broke this up into $4$ subcases as follows:

Case $1$: Small wall only. I get an average walk distance of $2.6262$.
Case $2$: Large wall only. I get an average walk distance of $3.4293$.
Case $3$: Both walls.  I get an average walk distance of $3.5181$.
Case $4$: no walls. Average walk distance is $2.0000$.

Remember cases $1$ and $3$ each only happen $12.5$% of the time, while cases $2$ and $4$ both each happen $37.5$% of the time , so the weighted average yields an average walk length of $2.804$ miles which is consistent with my other "Monte Carlo" type simulation.  This one busts up the middle mile into $999$ equidistant pieces so I am simulating possible wall positions every $5.28$ feet.  The walls in my simulation can be at mile markers $.501$, $.502$... $1.498$, $1.499$ but never at $0.5$ and never at $1.5$.

Runtime, (using an interpreted language), is about $1.5$ seconds.

$UPDATE~~2$ - My first effort to beat the simple always try to aim at B strategy worked but was kinda slow on my computer.  I just picked $3$ variable slopes, one for each half mile segment.  The $4$th slope is a given it just aims back down to B.  I gave the $3$ slopes "liberty" like from $0.1$ to $1.0$ for the first $2$.  I suspected the optimal shape would be a curve so I allowed the program to slope back down for the $3$rd slope (but still investigated some upslopes too for that segment).  When I got the general shape of the curve via the $3$ "ballpark" slopes (not yet optimal), then I tightened the range on the slopes but with more precision.  This seemed to almost work but since it was a Monte Carlo type simulation with random values, problem was I was not getting the same results each run.  I could somehow change the simulation to be more like my direct at B simulation where I walk each subcase with all possible wall positions and then just assign a weight to those cases then come up with an overall weighted average which works, but  requires some accurate programming.  This problem is pretty impressive in that shortcuts will get you close but then someone else more sophisticated with better tools can come along and get a better answer.  It is also impressive in that the math and simulation required is advanced, yet conceptually the problem is easy to understand (for example a child could likely understand the problem but not likely solve it).

$UPDATE~~3$ - I have an idea I will be pursuing. For simulation,  the optimal solution is somewhat elusive cuz it would require walking virtually all possible paths (within reason) and that takes too much computational time.  If however, I can just pick a reasonable number of slopes such as $8$ of them as I did to well approximate the optimal curve from the previous single wall problem,  perhaps I can get very close to optimal.

So far all I have are $3$ slopes with the $4$th slope being automatic as it will always go from mile marker $1.5$ directly to B since no wall will ever be there.  Here is what I have so far:

Segment $1$: From $0.0$ to $0.5$ : slope $.49$
Segment $2$: From $0.5$ to $1.0$ : slope $.25$
Segment $3$: From $1.0$ to $1.5$ : slope $-.22$
Segment $4$: From $1.5$ to $2.0$ : slope $-.52$

Average walk distance is $2.7089$ miles. ($1,000,000$ random wall walks).

Perhaps next what I can do is pick some midslope between segment $1$ and $2$ for example and see if that improves things any.  For example, keep $.49$ slope the first half mile but instead of a fixed slope of $.25$ the next half mile, perhaps try $.35$ and $.15$ each a $1/4$ mile.  Those have the same average slope but better approximates a curve.  When I did this I got a slight improvement to $2.7065$ (also $1,000,000$ random wall walks).

$UPDATE~~4$ - Here is the graph of the best walk path I have so far.  The axis are y values on the left (miles above the centerline), and across the bottom are the x values in $1/4$ mile increments.  Notice the near symmetry of the graph.  I get about $2.704$ miles average walk length for this.  The length of the rough curve itself is about $2.152$ miles.

[image]

$UPDATE~~5$ - A function, y=f(x) which creates a symmetric curve and is fairly simple is y = $-0.0257143x^2 + 0.205714x - 0.05$.  This is using units of $1/4$ mile for the x axis and not including the starting point A and stopping point B which we know are at y=$0$.  For the x values we go from $1$ to $7$ which represents $1/4$ to $7/4$ of a mile from A along the x axis.  The y points we hit are $.13, .26, .33, .37, .33, .26, .13$ and of course $0$ at A and B.  This function generates a smoother curve of the approximated curve shown above.

Actually something "suspicious" is going on here.  This answer seems too simple yet it works...  Notice that on the graph, the middle mile (from x values $2$ to $6$ which represents mile markers $2/4$ to $6/4$) go roughly from y positions $.25$ at the corners to $.375$ in the middle.  $.25$ is half the height of the small wall and $.375$ is half the average of the $2$ wall heights.  If you just pick those y values and then connect them with a smooth curve, it should be near optimal!  How is that for simple?   Someone could have actually guessed this solution and be very close to optimal with virtually no math! (they just have to know how to take the average of $2$ numbers) and connect dots.  I think probably a $7$ year old can do that.

A super simple approximation to this curve would be $0.5$ slope the first half mile, then $0.25$ slope the next half mile, then a mirror image on the other side of mile marker $1$ (symmetrically going back down to B).  It seems ironic that a near optimal solution to a very complex problem appears to be super simple (once I did some simulation and got the general shape of the curve).  I wonder if this is a coincidence or if it is somehow related to the height of the $2$ walls.  I suppose I could change the height of the $2$ walls in my simulation program and see what I get if the relationship holds.  It may also be related to the probabilities of each wall.

Comment: I think the issue may be that everyone who has the time and inclination to apply a more mathematical approach to the problem is all worn out from your last problem, which was about the level of a graduate school homework problem. Your best bet for getting takers for the current problem may be to update this answer every day or two with your simulation results, thus bumping the thread occasionally. Might not be bad to post a graph of your best path, although that may be problematical since the strategy changes after the first wall encounter.

Comment: Yes I agree that previous problem was a "bear".  I was really surprised at the level of mathematics required to solve it.  How about I use the time this thread stays active to do my own simulation and try to get a reasonable optimal solution and then offer a bounty of $100$ points (or possibly more like $150$) for someone to find an even better solution mathematically?  I find these types of problems really interesting even only using a computer to "walk" the paths and it helps keep my programming skills somewhat "sharp".  Okay good advice I will take it thanks.

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint/viewpoint, can you tell me what about this problem makes it more difficult than the previous one?  Is that 2nd wall throwing a monkey wrench into the analysis?  Do some graph problems like this boil down to simulation only cuz of too many "monkey wrenches"?  Does that mean before the days of computers they were unsolvable?

Comment: Also, the "flipside"/benefit of asking this similar question soon after the other one is the ideas are still fresh in the minds of the people that answered.  All the answers seemed very good so I upvoted them all but gave user5713492 the bounty cuz of the depth of the analysis (many charts/graphs, intense math...).  I gave the other person the checkmark not really cuz his answer was better, but because I wanted to reward both and he got more upvotes from other users anyway so I wanted to be fair to both.  Since this problem seems harder, maybe I will offer $150$ bounty points for it tomorrow.

Comment: Actually I think this problem is even more interesting than my previous one cuz of the interaction between the $2$ walls and the fact that the smaller wall (if close enough to the larger wall and coming after it), many times will not actually be an obstruction cuz of its smaller size.  I think the problem is well thought out and the optimal walk path is totally non obvious.  It may be a curve similar to the previous problem or it may be some "new" shape.  I can only explore a few simple shapes such as the upper part of a trapezoid or some function that creates an arch like a McDonalds arch.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one possible reason for the downvotes may be that @user5713492's suggestion to intentionally bump the thread occasionally was bad advice and it's rather annoying to see your question pop up all the time because of these edits.

Comment: @user5713492 If the previous question was at a graduate level, do you think this question would be well recieved on math overflow?

Comment: It's such a difficult problem but doesn't advance other areas of mathematics significantly in its solution. There are plenty of people on this site that can do damage to this problem, but it takes hours to make any progress. I finally got a little free time and looked a little at the hardest part of the problem where the first wall encountered is the big one, and before the halfway point, so the small wall still has to be accounted for. I've got it reduced to $2$ parameters from that point, but the algebra blows up in optimization. I hope I can post something in the morning.

Comment: My simulations gave me few problems too, but I ironed them out.  For the big wall first, in my simulation, I try to keep it as simple as possible.  I know the distance between the $2$ walls (since I used $2$ nested loops for them), therefore I know how much "drop" (in y)  there is when I hit the small wall, aiming at B.  If drop is > $0.5$, then I know I will bump the small wall.  If drop < $0.5$, then the current path directly towards B will already clear the small wall. You can see by my by case walk distances that the both wall case is only slightly longer than large wall only case.

Comment: I think this problem is simpler (relatively speaking), if it is broken up into subcases and then somehow recombined into an aggregate solution (such as I did in my simulation for a simple walk strategy).  I could take my code and try a more sophisticated walk path but I was waiting for someone else to offer a suggestion.  Assuming my previous Monte Carlo simulation was correct , the best I saw so far was about $2.7$ miles.  Since this question is harder than the single wall problem, I would accept solutions heavily biased with simulation and/or any tools available to help solve it.  Good luck.

Comment: I find it somewhat surprising that a conceptually "simple" problem is a "bear" (both mathematically speaking and for simulation), to get the optimal solution.  Of course non optimal solutions are much easier.  This might even be a good problem for a computer simulation type class as the students can compete with each other for the best (shortest path) solution.  I don't know of any "easy" way to code this and I even had some trouble with just a few points, getting different answers each run using random variable for wall positions.  I agree this problem requires some powerful tools to solve.

Comment: One frustrating thing about simulation of this problem is I cannot "lock"  certain points or slopes and hope to get an optimal solution.  All points need to be able to be "wiggled" since moving one point or slope can affect the other ones.   So I don't know of any easy way to code this other than get a  super fast computer and maybe a fast compiler (that generates fast executing code), and let 'er rip.  Perhaps start out with only a few points then when you get the general shape of the curve, get more points/slopes but don't "lock" any leave them flexible.  I think $8$ to $10$ points is good.

Comment: I am having a hard time interpreting your graph because you didn't create an $x$-axis that corresponds to the coordinates of your problem. Can you try simulating with (a subset of) the points that I posted last night so we can check whether I am doing things right this time? The algebra involved in this enterprise is just brutal and even though I checked some things with Wolfram|Alpha and others numerically there is so much potential for error that it's difficult to be confident in my partial solution. It is somewhat worrisome that I'm still not all that near your best path.

Comment: The x-axis IS in the correct coordinates, they are just in $1/4$ mile increments as stated.  This problem to me seems  very "fishy" cuz it appears the near optimal path is super simple as described.  Basically even a $2$ slope (or symmetric $1$ slope) caret shape path sloping up $0.375$ in the first mile then $-0.375$ slope back down to B the 2nd mile does VERY well at about $2.72$ miles.  Adding more slopes to better approximate a curve may cut only a few hundreths of a mile off the average path.  I guess this is one of those  problems where simulation seems to be the better choice.

Comment: Is there anything I can do (simulationwise) to assist you with your mathematical calculations?  I already posted my partial results like small wall only, large wall only... so  you can use those to crosscheck.  If your results match those that is encouraging since it doubtful we both made the same mistake.  Actually my code is rather simple (no recursion, not much precomputing...) and the practice I had coding the previous single wall problem helped me   to  code this double wall problem much easierly (I made that word up).   My $2$ programs for dual wall crosscheck/match so that is good too.

Comment: One issue with your graph is that the tic marks are not on the numbers, but between them. What kind of software makes graphs like that by default? Also zero is not on the graph. Slap your graphing software around until it stops doing those two horrible things. My path is significantly different from yours, especially towards the end. Can you run your simulation with my points to see whether it improves slightly on your current path? If it doesn't either my math or your simulation is wrong. I have solved the part of the problem where the small wall is hit first. Will post. x-axis: 0 to 2!

Comment: I used an old version of Microsoft Excel (97) but I also posted my near optimal slopes so the graph can be easily rebuilt using your favorite software instead.  It is possible my simulation has bugs but I doubt it cuz the numbers look like they are behaving.  Remember the small wall hit first scenario in the $2$ wall scenario is relatively rare, so that partial solution may not be even close to the overall solution.  My simulation handles ALL cases (no walls, small wall only, large wall only, small wall before large wall, large wall before small wall) all in the proper proportion.

Comment: Also the tic marks are the in between markers ($1/8$th mile markers)  The y value points line up with the x value numbers (those represent $1/4$ miles so for example $6$ is the $6/4$ mile marker which is the $1.5$ mile marker).  The plot doesn't start at $0$ cuz there is no 0 row in my spreadsheet but it can be visually/mentally inserted easily.  Obviously it starts at 0 which is the starting point of A.  To me it doesn't look like the optimal curve is symmetrical.  It appears to peak a little beyond mile marker $1$, perhaps close to $1.2$, then curves back down to B, steeply after mile $1.5$.

Comment: **Never** make a line graph in Excel. Always use the graph that in some versions is called 'XY graph' and in others 'scatter graph'. Put the x-values in one column and the y-values in the column to the right of them. Select the whole block of data, x and y together, and make a scatter graph. Excel will show you some options; choose the picture with markers and straight lines connecting them. Add axis labels and a title to your graph. Presentation is important on a website read by so many random people. Also run your simulation with my points. I want to find why the discrepancy in our paths.

Comment: It is running now overnight and the best $1/4$ mile each slopes I have thus far (but may change some) are $.5, .6, .4, .3, -.1, -.4, -.65, -.65$)  The the XY points hit (thus far) are $(0,0), (.25, .125), (.5, .275), (.75, .375),(1,.45) ,(1.25, .425), (1.5, .325),(1.75, .1625),(2,0)$